# Redux state changes on load even though no action has been dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

For some reason, when I load my webapp, the state 'currentView' is set to "subjects" instead of the initial value "schools" even though there was no action dispatched. Why is this the case?

**actions.js**

```
export function showSubjects(schoolId) {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_SUBJECTS',
    schoolId
  };
}
```

**browse.js**

```
const initialState = {
    currentView: 'schools',
    schools: [{id: 'AAAA', name: 'aaaa'}, {id: 'BBBB', name: 'bbbb'}],
    subjects: [{id: 'CCC', name: 'ccc'}, {id: 'DDD', name: 'ddd'}]
};

function browse(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_SUBJECTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        currentView: 'subjects'
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default browse;
```

**BrowseReduxContainer.jsx**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { showSubjects } from '../actions/actions';
import Browse from '../components/Browse.jsx';

function propsFilter(state) {
  switch (state.currentView) {
    case 'schools':
      return state.schools;
    case 'subjects':
      return state.subjects;
    default:
      throw new Error(`No such view: ${state.currentView}`);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  schools: propsFilter(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showSubjects: (schoolId) => {
    dispatch(showSubjects(schoolId));
  }
});

const BrowseReduxContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Browse);

export default BrowseReduxContainer;
```

**Browse.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const Browse = (props) => (
  <div>
    {props.schools.map((school) => (
      <RaisedButton key={school.id} label={school.name} onClick={props.showSubjects(school.id)} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default Browse;
```

Other relevant files, if necessary, can be viewed here: https://github.com/Joonpark13/serif.nu/tree/feature/browse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RaisedButton causes the issue:

```
<RaisedButton key={school.id} label={school.name} onClick={props.showSubjects(school.id)} />
```

You execute `showSubjects` in the `onClick` handler instead of passing a reference. Instead, it should be `onClick={() => props.showSubjects(school.id)}` so that the function is only executed after the click.

As an alternative, you can also modify your `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showSubjects: (schoolId) => () => {
    dispatch(showSubjects(schoolId));
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed the callback. Thank you.